# How can I be notified when a server comes back up?

Tags: linux, monitoring, ping

So far I've determined that I can use the ping command to send a ping to said server every 15 minutes or so in a command prompt window in Linux like so:

```
ping -i 900 <server-address>
```

The 900 is specified in seconds and 900 seconds is 15 minutes.

I believe the server to be overloaded already and that is why it is not responding.

Is there any way to make an audible bell sound when the server is actually pinged successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the below script it will work.

```
while :
  do
  ping -c1 <server-ip-address>
  if [ $? ] ; then 
    echo -e "\a"
    break
  fi
  sleep 900
done
```